# error js + firebase. Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '​'

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, webpack-config

[image: js code]

[image: html code]

[image: config code]

```
    [![error method ][4]][4]
```

I think that the problam is in the webpack.config.js code but I dont know

Comment: main error method        index.js:1 
        
       Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '​' (41:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| adduserform.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
|     e.preventDefault()
> }​)​
    at eval (index.js:1:7)
    at Object../src/index.js (bundle.js:18:1)
    at bundle.js:29:48
    at bundle.js:31:12
eval @ index.js:1
./src/index.js @ bundle.js:18
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:29
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:31

Comment: Please post code and errors as text, and edit your question instead of posting details in comments.